# How to get nested array value from Query String Parameter and convert it to specific List of object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httprequest

I have this Query Parameter String as a request:

[image]
In order to make it readable:

```
draw:3
columns[0][data]:
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:false
columns[0][orderable]:false
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:Id
columns[1][name]:Id
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:Name
columns[2][name]:Name
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
columns[3][data]:Address
columns[3][name]:Address
columns[3][searchable]:true
columns[3][orderable]:true
columns[3][search][value]:
columns[3][search][regex]:false
columns[4][data]:ZipCode
columns[4][name]:Zip Code
columns[4][searchable]:true
columns[4][orderable]:true
columns[4][search][value]:
columns[4][search][regex]:false
columns[5][data]:EmailAddress
columns[5][name]:Email Address
columns[5][searchable]:true
columns[5][orderable]:true
columns[5][search][value]:
columns[5][search][regex]:false
columns[6][data]:PhoneNumber
columns[6][name]:Phone Number
columns[6][searchable]:true
columns[6][orderable]:true
columns[6][search][value]:
columns[6][search][regex]:false
columns[7][data]:UserName
columns[7][name]:User Name
columns[7][searchable]:true
columns[7][orderable]:true
columns[7][search][value]:
columns[7][search][regex]:false
columns[8][data]:Password
columns[8][name]:Password
columns[8][searchable]:true
columns[8][orderable]:true
columns[8][search][value]:
columns[8][search][regex]:false
columns[9][data]:LastUpdate
columns[9][name]:Last Update
columns[9][searchable]:true
columns[9][orderable]:true
columns[9][search][value]:
columns[9][search][regex]:false
columns[10][data]:Decimal
columns[10][name]:Decimal
columns[10][searchable]:true
columns[10][orderable]:true
columns[10][search][value]:
columns[10][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:1
order[0][dir]:asc
start:0
length:675
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
_:1479300847314
```

I need to get the `columns` parameter, and convert it to List with an object with `data:string`, `name:string`, `searchable:boolean`, `orderable:boolean`, and `search:object` parameters. However, I'm still wondering on how to get nested array from Query Parameter String. This is what I have tried:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string draw = Request.QueryString["draw"]; //it works
    object columns1 = Request.QueryString["columns"]; //null
    object columns2 = Request["columns"]; //null
    var columns3 = Request["columns"]; //null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are trying to retrieve the value from the QueryString. You are passing each array items properties separately, so that is how you need to retrieve their values. I tested it and this is how you call each of those values:

```
string draw = Request.QueryString("draw");
object columnData0 = Request.QueryString("columns[0][data]");
object columnName0 = Request("columns[0][name]");
object columnSearchable0 = Request("columns[0][searchable]");
object columnOrderable0 = Request("columns[0][orderable]");
```

I suggest looking at other ways to to pass an array via url.